# Jquery using this to animate only the selected item

Tags: jquery

Hi I have 3 repetitions of the same block and I want to animate the hovered block, not the other. The script below animates all the blocks. How do i use jquery "this" to just animate the hovered div? And I also have .img class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".HomeClaimWrapper").hover(function () {
    $(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").stop().animate({
      top: "-10px"
    }, 300);
  });

  $(".HomeClaimWrapper").mouseout(function () {
    $(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").stop().animate({
      top: "-5px"
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this bind event like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").hover(function(){
       $(this).stop().animate({
       top: "-10px"
       }, 300 );
    });

    $.each($(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").mouseout(function(){
       $(this).stop().animate({
       top: "-5px"
       }, 300 );
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `this` as the selector within the event handler:

```
$(function(){
    $(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: "-10px"
        }, 300 );
    });

    $(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
        top: "-5px"
        }, 300 );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").hover(function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({
         top: "-10px"
         }, 300 );
     });

  $(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").mouseout(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({
         top: "-5px"
         }, 300 );
  });
});
```

Please pay attention with `.img`. If you don't see a `class="img"` somewhere in your code then delete `.` and leave `img`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").hover(function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({
       top: "-10px"
     }, 300 );
   });

   $(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").mouseout(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({
        top: "-5px"
      }, 300 );
   });
});
```

**EDIT:** to animate `img` on hover of `div`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".HomeClaimWrapper").hover(function(){
     $(this).find(".img").stop().animate({
       top: "-10px"
     }, 300 );
   });

   $(".HomeClaimWrapper").mouseout(function(){
      $(this).find(".img").stop().animate({
        top: "-5px"
      }, 300 );
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks. What if I want to animate the image whne the whole dive is hovered. For an example  $(".HomeClaimWrapper").hover(function() - how to animate only he image in the HomeClaimWrapper div?

Comment: edited my answer and yeah be sure what `snake Eyes` has written in his answer that if theres no `.img` class then just use `img` instead of using `.img`

Answer (score 0):

replace $('.HomeClaimWrapper .img') with $(this)

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to keep my state definitions in one place, and the newer versions of jQuery make that easy for hover events:

```
$(function(){
    $(".HomeClaimWrapper .img").hover(function(e){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: e.type == 'mouseenter' ? "-10px" : "-5px"
        }, 300 );
    });
});
```

That, by the way, is the current single-parameter definition, so I think your (and the other answers here) sample won't do quite what you want. It will trigger on both mouse enter and leave.

If you want them separate, there's a two parameter version of hover.